# What are "extended integer types"?

Tags: c, gcc, c99

Quoting from the book I'm reading:

> 1. `signed char, signed short int, signed int, signed long int, signed long long int` are called **standard signed integer types**
> 2. `unsigned char, unsigned short int, unsigned int, unsigned long int, unsigned long long int, _Bool` are called **standard unsigned
>    integer types**
> 3. In addition to the standard integer types, the C99 standard allows implementation-defined **extended integer types**, both signed and
>    unsigned. For example, a compiler might be provide signed and unsigned
>    128-bit integer types.

I've problem with 3rd point. What are these "extended integer types"? Any examples?

Comment: error: 'long long long' is too long for GCC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of the extended integer type is the `__int64` 64-bit signed integer type defined by MS Visual C. While this type is obviously an integral type, in older versions of MSVC it could not be obtained as `int`, `long int`, nor `long long int`. (MSVC added support for `long long int` in the meantime.)

Comment: This is not the best example as `MSVC` is c90 and c90 doesn't have *extended integer types*. They were introduced in c99.

Comment: @ouah Good point. I suppose it would be more correct to say that extended integer types were introduced to cover such a case.

Comment: note: also `__int128` that may be defined by gcc is *not* extended integer types because [GCC does not support any extended integer types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for the link. I wonder if this is a documentation oversight for platforms where GCC defines `__int128`. Except for the documentation claiming otherwise, it has all traits of an extended integer type: it implements integer arithmetic, it is not an alias for one of the standard integer types, it comes in signed and unsigned variety, it has a fixed width, and it is represented in binary. If it looks like a duck...

Comment: @user4815162342: `sizeof(intmax_t)` may be less than `sizeof(__int128)` on gcc. It rules out the possibility that `__int128` is an extended integer type.

Answer (score 7):

Extended integer types are implementation-specific integer types that are provided as an extension. Because almost everything about such extensions is implementation-defined, the standard can’t say much about them. However, a C++09 proposal provides a framework for implementing such extensions in a way that doesn’t interfere with the behavior of standard compliant programs.

you should refer [this](http://www.9wy.net/onlinebook/CPrimerPlus5/app02lev1sec6.html),which covers everything about extended integer types.