# Example of an extended integer type?

Tags: c

As of C99, C supports implementation-defined extended integer types (6.2.5 p7).  Does any implementation actually implement an extended integer type?

I'm aware of gcc's `__int128`, which is currently treated as a language extension and is not formally listed as an extended integer type in gcc's documentation of implementation-defined behavior (J.3.5).  I couldn't find anything mentioned in the documentation for clang or MSVC.  Solaris states that there are no extended integer types.

There is some related discussion at [What are “extended integer types”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403600/what-are-extended-integer-types), but the only other candidate mentioned is `__int64` in an older version of MSVC, and the comments seem to agree that it's not a formal extended integer type due to that version of MSVC being C90.

Comment: Perhaps [int24_t](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1081917.aspx)?

Comment: Curious.  The GCC manual does say that `__int128` is available only on platforms that have a wide enough integer mode.  Is it in fact available anywhere where it is not an alias for one of the standard integer types (presumably `long long int`)?

Comment: @chux Please make that an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) has 64-bit `long`, `long long`, and `intmax_t` and provides `__int128` in a Ubuntu 19.04 VM.

Comment: `__int128` in GCC is not an “extended integer type” in the sense of the C standard. Let me look up the quote from a GCC developer… But for one, it is wider than `intmax_t` on, say, x86-64, which a normal extended integer type cannot be.

Comment: Yes, exactly for that reason: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84764 “__int128 is not an extended integer type in the C sense.  The main reason is
because intmax_t is not defined as __int128.”

Comment: Interesting, @PascalCuoq, especially in its backwardness.  `__int128` being neither a standard nor an extended integer type effectively means that the language standard does not define any behavior for it.  I suppose there must be some reason that that choice was preferable to making `intmax_t` be `__int128` on those machines that support the latter.

Comment: @PascalCuoq another reason is that there are no literal values for int128

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example of an extended integer type?
>   Does any implementation actually implement an extended integer type?

Various processors have a 24-bit width for instructions and constant memory.

Compilers supporting such Microchip processors offer 
[`(u)int24_t`](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1081917.aspx).

> int24_t types added to C99 The int24_t and uint24_t types (along with the existing __int24 and __uint24 types) are now available when using the C99 library and when CCI is not active.

---

Even though some compilers do offer  128-bit integer types, if that type was an *extended integer type*, the C library would require `(u)intmax_t` to be at least that width.  C11dr 7.20.1.5

C also requires "preprocessor arithmetic done in `intmax_t/uintmax_t`".

I suspect compilers offering `intN` (N > 64) do so as a *language extension*.

I  know of no compiler where `(u)int128_t` exist (as an *extended integer type*).