# gcc 7.3 128-bit unsigned integer operation

Tags: c, gcc, 128-bit, int128

I'm confused with the usage of 128-bit integer.
Please look at the test code:

```
uint128_t test_data = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF0101010101010101;
uint64_t test_data_h = test_data  >> 64;
uint64_t test_data_l = test_data ;
printf("test_data 0x %016llx %016llx\n", test_data_h, test_data_l);
```

I expect the `test_data_h` to be 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, but the result is :

```
test data 0x 0000000000000000 0101010101010101
```

Why is this?

Comment: Please spend one minute takint the [tour] to understand how this community works. And if some answer helps you, you should click the green checkmark to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning 128 bit integer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461318/assigning-128-bit-integer-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Many compilers do not support 128 bit constants.

Instead

```
// uint128_t test_data = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF0101010101010101;
uint128_t test_data = (((uint128_t) 0x00000000FFFFFFFF) << 64) | 0x0101010101010101;
```

Tip: enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: I see. I am using gcc 7.3.1. The solution you offered works! Thanks a lot. So it seems like that the default type for numeric integer is __int64_t ?

Comment: @oohu no, [*The type of the integer literal is the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which integer-suffix was used*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal#The_type_of_the_literal)

Comment: @oohu The type of a hex constant (without a suffix) is `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long`, the first one it value fits.

Answer (score 2):

GCC doesn't support 128-bit integer literal

> There is no support in GCC for expressing an integer constant of type `__int128` for targets with `long long` integer less than 128 bits wide.
>
> [128-bit Integers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html)

So you'll have to construct it from smaller parts `((unsigned __int128)high << 64) | low`

---

If you turned on all warnings you'll see

```
<source>:6:35: warning: integer constant is too large for its type
    6 |     unsigned __int128 test_data = 0x00000000FFFFFFFF0101010101010101;
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiXAEykADqmmEltTTv2DX7xTpTcytdW3tOJ1l5QNoGAmZiAm89A04ZOUwFT3jEgmDLGztHGQSklN906TL8s0Kw4siAShlUbWJkDgByAFIHAGYzZB0sAGoe/vVq/HoAOgQJ7B6ABgBBPsHaYe0xiamCfFR5xZX1tbMCUd1mMwgm056AdgAhU9H30e1ad2BzdFGJBdIgAOUYETDVMToZgJcb9AAio2WAA9lmj0WiAGLYnHY5acfGEgnEokTV5rD6fC4ANm4Yku4Mh0ISYgQcMRjIIUJhzHeJ362FGtLJbw%2B2hpdIZEK5zOYYlY7LB0u5sJFFI%2BzmIFyoED6Dk5Kt5KPGDgArPjqaxWMiTebOJbrT1TepaHrSEqmTzWe6DbL5fd%2BuTVpTiJgCO1aEi1etHvDTl0WqwQF1TV1SAYuss06hk%2BpRtI2h1MCb%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%2BM8QSRLEyTpPEiS5IUyysliFQ1A8rS6h0xoXH02IPP8AzaG8sHoj%2B6z3K0VJBAR5S4hqOHXJslHKk8pyQfMoLWgCujgpTYdwuTSLoti4Bj0SxsxPS/AiGIbL3Ty6q7Gy4r1FK%2Bdysq9ceZ3OrRYalA8GPTg%2B1INqOsoLrRx6vqQIG%2BghuA0dRog7pdZgxGZqQlDkDQg202Wkj1sIjAdvLMiKIVugTtorheAEfohFPVibs4%2B7eKeugXtEz6Ptk5F5OYRSrJUtS8Y04GQmJ3hochxPjJh7GQF4dGHNxnwNPzpHCZTlzc4J5JM6qLGiYr7g/MLQLfIHSmwpAiKopi7hRhl5BEpbZLZk4NKMvZzncslgqNn6fnBarWsQFNR5ku4Bxlm4ZZqWpYEe0eU1TTbodSHI80O9HcdJ0EOcq0XFcKpANoCGcNDar3afiicTA2ZIQRjpomdXgAB3AizhnYrVCiObMyYNhiWAYQNktMe5xSuolTgw9Ry3wXI/Z%2Br8CDv3qtuQwv8LIANOnREBYCIEhSpp3WBHZRgIIIEg7u9NGYElmA4BeOCkB4LfruIhxRvY/0ymQ12gDKGkFAcwcBh0KZQOpr0AY/QmGINGMg2K/dB7D12mVCmJ8z4zmgWOZM18ZzYOrKQOs1Ih6cEeJvR4u9Iimi3sCb2K1%2Bh0MvmY2c%2Bi27cIvjAicfihYtAQreTwucgA%3D%3D)

Because the type of an integer literal is [*“the first type in which the value can fit, from the list of types which depends on which numeric base and which `integer-suffix` was used”*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) and **the list of types doesn't contain non-standard types like `__int128`**.

C99 also supports [“extended integer types”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13403600/995714) and in the same page you can also see that

> If the value of the integer constant is too big to fit in any of the types allowed by suffix/base combination and the compiler supports extended integer types (such as `__int128`), the constant may be given the extended integer type; otherwise, the program is ill-formed.
>
> [integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant)

Unfortunately [`__int128` is **not** an extended integer type in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html). You can easily see that `intmax_t` maps to `long long` instead of `__int128`. Therefore you can't have `__int128` literal, unless the compiler has another extension, like ICC. You can see that there's no relevant integer literal warning from ICC in the [Godbolt link above](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiXAEykADqmmEltTTv2DX7xTpTcytdW3tOJ1l5QNoGAmZiAm89A04ZOUwFT3jEgmDLGztHGQSklN906TL8s0Kw4siAShlUbWJkDgByAFIHAGYzZB0sAGoe/vVq/HoAOgQJ7B6ABgBBPsHaYe0xiamCfFR5xZX1tbMCUd1mMwgm056AdgAhU9H30e1ad2BzdFGJBdIgAOUYETDVMToZgJcb9AAio2WAA9lmj0WiAGLYnHY5acfGEgnEokTV5rD6fC4ANm4Yku4Mh0ISYgQcMRjIIUJhzHeJ362FGtLJbw%2B2hpdIZEK5zOYYlY7LB0u5sJFFI%2BzmIFyoED6Dk5Kt5KPGDgArPjqaxWMiTebOJbrT1TepaHrSEqmTzWe6DbL5fd%2BuTVpTiJgCO1aEi1etHvDTl0WqwQF1TV1SAYuss06hk%2BpRtI2h1MCb%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%2BM8QSRLEyTpPEiS5IUyysliFQ1A8rS6h0xoXH02IPP8AzaG8sHoj%2B6z3K0VJBAR5S4hqOHXJslHKk8pyQfMoLWgCujgpTYdwuTSLoti4Bj0SxsxPS/AiGIbL3Ty6q7Gy4r1FK%2Bdysq9ceZ3OrRYalA8GPTg%2B1INqOsoLrRx6vqQIG%2BghuA0dRog7pdZgxGZqQlDkDQg202Wkj1sIjAdvLMiKIVugTtorheAEfohFPVibs4%2B7eKeugXtEz6Ptk5F5OYRSrJUtS8Y04GQmJ3hochxPjJh7GQF4dGHNxnwNPzpHCZTlzc4J5JM6qLGiYr7g/MLQLfIHSmwpAiKopi7hRhl5BEpbZLZk4NKMvZzncslgqNn6fnBarWsQFNR5ku4Bxlm4ZZqWpYEe0eU1TTbodSHI80O9HcdJ0EOcq0XFcKpANoCGcNDar3afiicTA2ZIQRjpomdXgAB3AizhnYrVCiObMyYNhiWAYQNktMe5xSuolTgw9Ry3wXI/Z%2Br8CDv3qtuQwv8LIANOnREBYCIEhSpp3WBHZRgIIIEg7u9NGYElmA4BeOCkB4LfruIhxRvY/0ymQ12gDKGkFAcwcBh0KZQOpr0AY/QmGINGMg2K/dB7D12mVCmJ8z4zmgWOZM18ZzYOrKQOs1Ih6cEeJvR4u9Iimi3sCb2K1%2Bh0MvmY2c%2Bi27cIvjAicfihYtAQreTwucgA%3D%3D)